# Probability of drawing a specific number out of a pool of numbers with multiple draws

Tags: probability

I have a pool of 100 different numbers, I draw 5 different numbers without putting them back into the pool. I want to calculate the chance of any single number being drawn.

So for example, what's the chance of the number 13 being drawn during those 5 draws?

I figured, the way to calculate this would be

$$\frac{1}{100}+(\frac{1}{99}*\frac{99}{100})+(\frac{1}{98}*\frac{98}{99})+(\frac{1}{97}*\frac{96}{97})+(\frac{1}{96}*\frac{95}{96})=0.0506$$

Which would mean the chance for that would be ~5.1%

Is this calculation correct? What is this calculation called and whats the formula for it?

Comment: before the process is started, the chances that the 5th ball is going to be #13 is $\frac{99}{100}\times\frac{98}{99}\times\frac{97}{98}\times\frac{96}{97}\times\frac{1}{96} = \frac{1}{100}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct formula: $$\Pr(E)=\frac{\text{number of draws}}{\text{number of numbers}}=\frac5{100}$$
where $E$ denotes the event that number $13$ will be drawn.

For $i=1,2,3,4,5$ let $E_n$ denote the event that number $13$ is drawn at the $i$-th draw.

Then $\Pr(E_1)=\frac1{100}$ i.e. the first term in your summation.

You can calculate $\Pr(E_2)=\Pr(E_2\mid E_1^c)\Pr(E_1^c)=\frac{1}{99}\times\frac{99}{100}=\frac1{100}$, i.e. the second term in your summation.

So these terms are okay, and if you had proceeded without making any mistakes you would have found $\Pr(E_i)=\frac1{100}$ for every $i$.

Now start wondering: can you find any reason that the probability of drawing number $13$ at e.g. the $2$-nd draw should differ from the probability of drawing number $13$ at e.g. the $4$-th draw???

Comment: I think maybe reasoning that 100 balls could be placed randomly into slots 1-100, then looking to see if #13 is in slot 1-5, makes it easier to see that 5/100 is the correct answer (by symmetry #13 is equally likely to be in any given group of 5 spaces, and is effectively the same overall experiment)

Comment: @Cato That's indeed a good startoff for the stimulated "wondering" of the OP.

Comment: @Cato Wow, that made it really easy to understand!

Comment: @drhab This could still technically be seen as hypergeometric distribution right? Basically for my case it would be a population size = 100, number of successes in population = 1, sample size = 5, and number of successes in sample = 1 ?

Comment: @Luke Yes. With outcome $\frac{\binom51\binom{95}0}{\binom{100}1}=\frac5{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is binomial distribution without replacement, and is known as Hypergeometric distribution. Please find more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 1):

your reasoning is on the right lines, but you aren't quite right, on draw 5 (for example), it has to have failed to be drawn 4 times

may I be lazy and assum just 3 draws, I get the below example

$P = \frac{1}{100} + \frac{99}{100}\times\frac{1}{99} + \frac{99}{100}\times\frac{98}{99}\times\frac{1}{98}  =  \frac{1}{100} + \frac{1}{100} +\frac{1}{100}  = \frac{3}{100} $

the overall chance for 3 draws is 3/100, and the chance it will have come up on any of the particular draws is 1/100 - for your 5 draws - it will be 5 / 100 -

Answer (score 0):

I know it s late but maybe somebody will find it helpful, you need to calculate probability of successful draw as well as probability of getting into that specific draw, which would be on first 100/100 (since it is your first draw), for second (100-1 draw you already did)/100 of total pool, so basically you would have formula like 100/100 * 1/100 + 99/100 * 1/99 + 98/100 * 1/98....etc.=0,05=5%. That is (when you think about it) the same as if you picked five numbers with one draw which is 100/100(probability that you draw first draw) * 5/100 (chance that you ll get specific number out of 100) which should equal exactly 5% too. If you wanted to calculate chances of getting it at 5th draw exactly that would be different however. Then youwouldstart of chancesof getting through draw starting by 99/100 chance to get through first draw where you actually cannot pull the desired number.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).